# Polymer brackets with chemfig

Tags: brackets, chemfig

I am trying to do the mechanism shown in the image. I am stuck in the second molecule. I don't know how to use brackets properly. I also need to put the asterisk as an exponent.
[image]

Comment: The benzophenone radical is not a polymer, so no need for `\polymerdelim` here. You could get away with using `\chemleft[` and `\chemright]` as for example shown here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354474/134144 or here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59820/134144

Comment: Very helpful links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    
\schemestart
\chemfig{[:-30]*6(=-=(-C(=[6]O)(=[2,,,,draw=none]\phantom{O})-*6(=-=-=-))-=-)}
\arrow{->[$h\nu$]}[,1.5]
\chemleft[\chemfig{[:-30]*6(=-=(-C(=[6]O)(=[2,,,,draw=none]\phantom{O})-*6(=-=-=-))-=-)}\chemright]
\schemestop
\chemmove{
    \node at ([shift={(3pt,-2pt)}]c2.north east) {$\ast$};
}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It should be `$h\nu$` ;)

Comment: @cgnieder you are right. Thanks. I fixed it.